# c++ Unicode string comparison with confusable character. example ( U 0054) should be == (U03A4) etc

Tags: c++, unicode

I have Unicode  string and I want to compare with the following requirements.

Confusable s [1] character should be consider the same character, 
 example: T (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T U 0054) should be ==  T (GREEK CAPITAL LETTER TAU U03A4) etc

(* [1] example  http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp?a=TESTt&r=None*)

http://www.unicode.org/Public/security/revision-03/confusablesSummary.txt

I will use the above file in order to make the code, but if there are already any free libraries I would prefer to use it.

I am thinking that the code would create a temporary `ustring` in which every confusable  character would be replaced with the corresponding latin character.

In the real program I will be testing 10x5000x10000 strings containing one word each.

Test program:

```
 std::locale::global(std::locale(""));

 std::cout.imbue(std::locale());

 Glib::ustring s1,s2;

 s1="TEST";

 s2="TΕST";

 s1.normalize(Glib::NORMALIZE_NFKD    );

 s2.normalize(Glib::NORMALIZE_NFKD   );

 std::cout<<"1->true, 0->false  (s1==s2) =>  "<<(s1==s2)<<"\n";
```

Test program output:

```
1->true, 0->false  (s1==s2) =>  0
```

Ubuntu **locale** command Output:

```
Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit>$ locale  
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**Thank you for your time!**

Comment: When 160 characters don't suffice, Twitter users start posting on Stack Overflow... :-S

Comment: This looks like a simple matter of parsing the data file, building up a map from input characters to replacement characters, and applying that to the text file.

Comment: Sorry for my English. The question: " How to compare unicode string with  confusable character."  maybe using the "uspoof_getSkeleton "http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uspoof_8h.html#a848c780fd8a59f18e1835608e6fe6b76

Comment: From "I will use the above file in order to make the code, but if there are already any free libraries I would prefer to use it" I think the question is "Are there any free libraries which provide the functionality I intend to implement?"

Comment: @JoeGauterin yes you are right. A good library candidate  should be the ICU with the "uspoof_getSkeleton :(Get the "skeleton" for an identifier string.Identifier Skeletons: A skeleton is a transformation of an identifier, such that all identifiers that are confusable with each other have the same skeleton. Using skeletons, it is possible to build a dictionary data structure for a set of identifiers, and then quickly test whether a new identifier is confusable with an identifier already in the set. The uspoof_getSkeleton() family of functions will produce the skeleton from an identifier.)

Comment: This isn't as simple as it sounds if you want to use the *entire* database from the Unicode consortium: there isn't a 1-to-1 mapping between confusable characters.  For example, U+2474 PARENTHESIZED DIGIT 1 "⑴" can be confused with the the three-character sequence of U+0028 U+0031 U+0029 "(1)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user1675224 says you should be using ICU rather than attempting to roll your own algorithm.

For example, to use [`uspoof_areConfusable`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uspoof_8h.html#a30478be8a197dd7c3ac19a2a94ad8c6d):

```
UErrorCode status = 0;
USpoofChecker *sc = uspoof_open(&status);
int result = uspoof_areConfusable(sc, s1.data(), s1.length(), s2.data(), s2.length(), &status);
uspoof_close(sc);
```

If you're comparing large numbers of strings against each other, you should convert them to their skeletons using `uspoof_getSkeleton`, and put that in a set or hash set.

Answer (score 0):

```
 std::string s1,s2;
    s1="TEst";
    s2="TΕst";
    std::cout<<" s1.length()="<<s1.length()<<"\n";
    std::cout<<" s2.length()="<<s2.length()<<"\n";

 UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR ;
 USpoofChecker *sc = uspoof_open(&status);
 char p[100];
 int result = uspoof_getSkeletonUTF8    (sc,USPOOF_ANY_CASE, s1.data(),s1.length(),p,100,&status);
 std::string skeleton1(p,result);
 std::cout<<" result in bytes="<<result<<" status="<<status<<"\n";
 std::cout<<" skeleton1="<<skeleton1<<"\n";
 std::cout<<"1->true, 0->false  (s1==skeleton1) =>  "<<(s1==skeleton1)<<"\n";
 //
 char p2[100];
 int result2 = uspoof_getSkeletonUTF8   (sc,USPOOF_ANY_CASE , s2.data(),s2.length(),p2,100,&status);
 std::string skeleton2(p2,result2);
 std::cout<<" result2 in bytes="<<result2<<" status="<<status<<"\n";
 std::cout<<" skeleton2="<<skeleton2<<"\n";
 std::cout<<"1->true, 0->false  (s2==skeleton2) =>  "<<(s2==skeleton2)<<"\n";
 std::cout<<"1->true, 0->false  (s1==s2) =>  "<<(s1==s2)<<"\n";
 std::cout<<"1->true, 0->false  (skeleton1==skeleton2) =>  "<<(skeleton1==skeleton2)<<"\n";
 //
 uspoof_close(sc);
```

Output

```
 s1.length()=4
 s2.length()=5
 result in bytes=4 status=0
 skeleton1=TEst
 1->true, 0->false  (s1==skeleton1) =>  1
 result2 in bytes=4 status=0
 skeleton2=TEst
 1->true, 0->false  (s2==skeleton2) =>  0
 1->true, 0->false  (s1==s2) =>  0
 1->true, 0->false  (skeleton1==skeleton2) =>  1
```

Thank you.